# How to concatenate string in php?

Tags: php, foreach, concatenation

How to concatenate string in image source. I try to set  base path dynamic in image source but  it does not work. I am also using in fore each loop. any body can help me, give me some suggestion. I am new in php.

Here is my php code-

```
$base_path  =   'https://odesk.com';

$listing = '';
$count=1;
if(sizeOf($entry['contents'])>0){   
foreach($entry['contents'] as $child) {
    $count++;
    $cp = $child['path'];
    $cn = basename($cp);
    $image='';

    $cp = htmlspecialchars($cp);
    $link = getPath("?path=".htmlspecialchars($cp));

    if ($child['is_dir']) 
    {

    $image ='<img src="'@$base_path'/images/folder.png" width="20">';// i want here add base path
    $cn .= '/';
    }else{
    $image ='<input type="checkbox" value="'.$child['rev'].'" id="'.$child['rev'].'" name="checkbox_value[]" onclick="saveimages('.@$_SESSION['products_id'].',`'.@$path.'`,`'.@$cn.'`,this.value,event)" class="checked">&nbsp;<img src="https://odesk.com/images/image_dropbox.png" width="15">';
    }


    if($count%2==0){
    $listing .= "<div class='white'>$image&nbsp;<a id='a1' style='text-decoration: none;vertical-align:super;color:black;' href='$link'>$cn</a></div>";
    }else{
    $listing .= "<div class='white'>$image&nbsp;<a id='a1' style='text-decoration: none;vertical-align:super;color:black;' href='$link'>$cn</a></div>";
    }

}
}else{
    $listing = "<div align='center' class='white'><span style='color:red; text-align:center;'>No folders & files are available.</span></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `.` for concatenating values in PHP.

Replace following line

```
$image ='<img src="'@$base_path'/images/folder.png" width="20">';/
```

with

```
$image ='<img src="'.$base_path.'/images/folder.png" width="20">';/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse variables in your strings you have to use double quotes. This is described in the [Variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) section in the Strings documentation.

The following code will work:

```
$image = "<img src='$base_path/images/folder.png' width='20'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for `sprintf` 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
$image = sprintf('<img src="%s/images/folder.png" width="20">', $base_path);
```