# WP, PHP: How to concatenate function after get_template_part()?

Tags: php, function, concatenation

Please be gentle, after nearly a week and much googling, stack-o, stack-x, wp codex, php codex review of concatenation ( . && .= ) and ob_* functions, that I'm at an impasse on how to concatenate get_template_part( 'template' ) with custom_function() immediately after, custom_function() is stored in a child theme functions.php file.

What I am aiming to accomplish is that the custom_function() renders, appends, or otherwise concatenates immediately after the $wo_query/ get_template_part() has completed its execution.

Described below, is what I've attempted prior to posing this question in no specific order and not in its entirety because of readability, and all the locations of where variables and get_template_part() is positioned within the condition in which I am attempting to perform this execution.

**TL;DR**
Essentially, $wp_query/ get_template_part() is default template provided by theme, where I am working on appending/ concatenating a custom_function() to output supplemental posts to meet a minimum number of posts when $wp_query/ get_template_part() does not meet the minimum 'posts_per_page'.

Currently, I am able to output $wp_query/ get_template_part() posts (one at a time) with custom_function() posts  iterating in between each $wp_query/ get_template_part() output...
(Ex: $wp_query/ get_template_part() post(1), custom_function() posts (6), $wp_query/ get_template_part() post(1), custom_function() posts (6), etc... until $wp_query/ get_template_part() posts are completely done outputting/ rendering)

**Note:** custom_function() uses a tax_query() to supplement posts that are 'IN' or 'Exists' which does return what I am looking for, in terms of post content type.

The difficulties I am experiencing is concatenating custom_function() posts immediately AFTER $wp_query/ get_template_part() output without the iteration in between each $wp_query/ get_template_part() post.

Thank you for taking the time to read this verbose description, and any guidance would be awesome from this great community would be fantastic.

1. Directly concatenating get_template_part() with custom_function()

```
.. elseif ( 'post' === get_post_type() && ! in_category( $custom_cats, get_the_ID() ) ):
get_template_part( 'template-parts/blog/' . $custom_layout . '/content' ) . custom_function();
```

returns WP critical error

2. Assignment of get_template_part() and custom_function() to variables, the concatenating

```
.. elseif ( 'post' === get_post_type() && ! in_category( $custom_cats, get_the_ID() ) ):
$gtp = get_template_part();
$cf = custom_function();

echo $gtp . $cf;
```

returns all get_template_part() posts, however are iterated by the elseif loop with custom_function()...for example:

$wp_query/ get_template_part() returns 4 posts for get_template_part(), however will render 1 post, followed by custom_function() of 6 posts, then another single $wp_query/ get_template_part() post, then another 6, until all $wp_query/ get_template_part() posts are complete, the custom_function() post output completes, rather than outputting all 4 $wp_query/ get_template_part() posts, then all 6 custom_function() posts.

3. Assignment of get_template_part() and custom_function() to variables with ob_* (ob_start(), ob_get_contents(), ob_end_clean() && ob_end_flush())

```
.. elseif ( 'post' === get_post_type() && ! in_category( $custom_cats, get_the_ID() ) ):

ob_start();
$gtp = get_template_part();
$cf = custom_function();

$gtp = ob_get_contents();
$cf .= ob_get_contents();

ob_end_flush();
```

ob_end_flush() returns example 2's results, which is not exactly what I am looking for ($wp_query/ get_template_part() return all posts, then custom_function() concatenates and returns remainder.

ob_end_clean() returns null for both get_template_part() and custom_function().

Similarly, I've attempted to move $gtp = ob_get_contents() && $cf .= ob_get_contents() variable declarations outside of ob_end_flush() to execute, and returns that odd iteration, noted above.

4. Adding html tags  get_template_part()  ... and then ...  custom_function()  to separate output

```
.. elseif ( 'post' === get_post_type() && ! in_category( $custom_cats, get_the_ID() ) ):
?>
<div><?php get_template_part(); ?></div>
<div><?php custom_function(); ?></div>
```

Again, this methodology also returns that odd $wp_query/ get_template_part(), custom_function() iteration, rather than concatenating to the end of the completed $wp_query/ get_template_part() output.  I thought that the ob_* functions would be able to "hold" the get_template_part() output until custom_function() is concatenated for output to be executed by ob_end_flush().

Additionally, I've attempted locate_template() which resulted in a critical error, which is likely because I may not have the best understanding, even after reading Justin Tadlocks [How to load files within WordPress themes](https://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/17/how-to-load-files-within-wordpress-themes).  This also, lead me down the include, include_once, require, require_once research and testing, which seemed to not be what would reconcile what I am looking for.

Other Stack-O posts I've looked into (not an exhaustive list, rather a jist of my thought process):

- [How to Concatenate String in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761965/how-to-concatenate-string-in-php)
- [How to concatenate 2 functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154322/how-to-concatenate-2-function-in-php)
- [How to concatenate two arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318013/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-php)
- [Setting up two output buffers with different contents in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800587/php-setting-up-two-output-buffers-with-different-contents-in-while-loop)
- [Concatenate output of php function into string](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/354856/concatenate-output-of-php-function-into-string?rq=1)
- [PHP syntax how to concatenate properly echo bloginfo stylesheet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258195/php-syntax-how-to-concatenate-properly-echo-bloginfostylesheet-directory)

Comment: **Note**  I've had to abbreviate some of the things I've attempted and some of the resources I've looked in to, because Stack-O prompted my OP as "spam" -> I've also looked in to posts, such as: [PHP setting up two output buffers with different contents in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800587/php-setting-up-two-output-buffers-with-different-contents-in-while-loop/71801415#71801415)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, clarification on 'be gentle' was in reference to complex theory and application.  I resolved this by taking a step back and broadening my view of the entire document.

Simple answer:

```
if( have_post() && ! empty( $custom_columns ){... get_template_part( 'default' ) ...}elseif ( 'post' === get_post_type() && ! in_category( $_custom_special_cats )) {  ... get_template_part( 'category_handler' ) ... }else {... get_template_part( 'fall_back' ) ...}custom_function();
```

What I was doing as I was working on `get_template_part( 'category_handler' )`  within my child theme, and was focusing solely within the  `elseif`  condition, once I took a step away and I thought about how to troubleshoot, logic was in the right direction, application/ execution of where the function was to be appended was in the wrong location.

Here's what I did for comparison, for future Stack-O explorers:

```
if( have_post() && ! empty( $custom_columns ){... get_template_part( 'default' ) ...} elseif ( 'post' === get_post_type() && ! in_category( $_custom_special_cats )) {  ... get_template_part( 'category_handler' ) ... custom_function();  // my error lay here, by placing it within the loop } else { ... get_template_part( 'fall_back' ) ... }
```

The novice part was that I forgot that if the function is placed within the loop, the loop will OBVIOUSLY iterate the function and whatever posts are to be naturally iterated through the loop.

** ALSO if a more experienced SO user could explain to me how to 'write' code in a format that is more readable (vertically) instead of LTR (left-to-right) for easier readability for newer SO users that'd be pretty awesome.